# what kind of database solution suits my mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, database, api, cloud

I am looking into options how to realize the following use case. A iOS/Android user is using my app which gets its table view data populated by a cloud database solution. The user must be able to send back information (e.g. name + date) which needs to be send back to the database and gets stored there in a/different table/s. Moreover, I would need the db-solution to run automated reports based on the information sent back by the users (e.g. in an excel file).
So far I only found ragic.com might suit my needs. But what other options are out there, which might not be as fancy looking but will get the job done. Thanks guys!
[image]

Comment: Both Android and iPhone use SQLite. But it's not what you're looking for. Your best bet is a WebService. AND for the Excel part, a plain CSV file will do the trick - just use **;** instead of **,**. But, agai, it's not your case. This is done server side. So, nothing to do on the mobiles. Server side you can have a NET platform, so... SQL Server and Excel are friends (let's say cousins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WebService is considered best practice regarding these matters. Have a look at this guys tutorial:

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-webservice-example/